# Double request when chrome developer tools open

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express, google-chrome-devtools

I've an odd problem: I have a very simple node/expressjs app (I have a much more complex one but this simple example shows the problem). This app has three routes, as shown here:

```
var i = 0;

app.route('/login')
.get(function(req, res){
    console.log('login', ++i);

    res.send('login');
})

app.route('/test')
.get(function(req, res){
    console.log('test', ++i);

    res.send('test');
})

app.route('/')
.get(function(req, res){
    console.log('index', ++i);

    res.send('index');
})
```

Pretty simple. Any time one of these routes is requested, `i` is incremented and logged, and it works fine, except when the chrome dev tools pane is open. When the dev tools are open, requesting either login or test will fire two requests. Here is the results of the log:

```
15:45:30 web.1  | index 1
15:45:33 web.1  | login 2
15:45:34 web.1  | login 3
15:45:37 web.1  | test 4
15:45:37 web.1  | test 5
15:45:41 web.1  | login 6
15:45:42 web.1  | login 7
15:45:45 web.1  | test 8
15:45:45 web.1  | test 9
15:45:48 web.1  | index 10
```

What's going on here. Is it a Chrome bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a semi-known issue with chrome.

Google has a discussion here that discusses possible work arounds-- I haven't found a real solution, but this should give you a good head start.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64810

Comment: Just ran into this.  Banged my head against my code for 20 minutes trying to figure out why double requests were being logged, then I closed the developer tools... and no more double requests.  Is this a regression?  Seems odd that I've never noticed the behavior.

Comment: It's 2017 and the problem still persists... lost many hours of work trying to "fix" my app...

Comment: August 2018 & still no fix. Lucky me, I saw this just after 5 minutes of struggle :)

Comment: From the link that bencripps gave us I found the solution that works for me. Just turn off Chrome's Adobe Acrobat extension by the following steps: click Chrome's customize icon --> More tools --> Extensions --> Find the Adobe Acrobat PDF extension and turn it off.

Comment: It's 2021 and I have this issue with only one of my images!