# What does :-infinity mean in Initiator column of Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

While debugging why my service worker (`sw.js`) gets loaded twice when I reload the page that registered it (that's background, not the question) I notice in the  'Initiator' column in Chrome dev tools the initiator is given as: `sw.js:-infinity`.

What does  `:-infinity` mean in this context?

Comment: Looks like a bug. It's a line number.

Comment: Regarding why the services loaded twice, It has to do with Chrome Bug which still exist as of now. Experiencing the same [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937015/double-request-when-chrome-developer-tools-open)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a Chrome bug because:

Infinity is a numerical value representing positive infinity. -Infinity is a numeric value that represents negative infinity. Infinity is displayed when the number exceeds the upper limit of floating point numbers, which is equal to 1,779693134862315E + 308.

Answer (score 0):

Likely a bug with Chrome. Some potential reasons(?):

- Web Workers (Which service workers are a subset of) run on a different thread, so it may cause issues when Chrome tries to get the line number.
- `infinity` is a JavaScript keyword, so Chrome Developer tools may be written in HTML/CSS/JS, and JS is [weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FjTS.jpg) to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I had set the css property 'background-image' to 'url("#")' (via a js variable). To fix it, I changed the js code so that the variable holds the whole css property, rather than just the URL - so it is initialised to 'none' (rather than '#'), and set to 'url(...)' when there is a valid URL to set it to.